# Module recommendation needed for recurring monthly membership plan?

Tags: commerce

I’m building a site that features yoga/excercise videos and will require users to sign up as members which will require a recurring monthly payment. Could someone recommend which modules to use for this? i see there are a few different options available. Any experience with something like this or advice would much appreciated, thanks!

i also need to make these videos inaccessible to non-members, something else to consider

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a [shopping question(http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) and should not be asked here. You can ask how to do things, but recommendations are too opinion based and too easy to get outdated and no longer valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options available.

I've seen this: https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_recurring which integrates with Drupal commerce. It doesn't have a stable version though.

For something more stable, and which is independent of the Drupal commerce module, try Recurly
https://www.drupal.org/project/recurly

Recurly is a 3rd party subscription billing system.

Using the Recurly roles module: https://www.drupal.org/project/recurly_roles

You can have people subscribe to your website, and assign a paid membership user role after signup and subscription. If a user stops the subscription, then you can take away the role.

Then configure your videos to only be accessible to the paid member role.